# Analytically solving for zeros of derivative of cubic spline interpolated data

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a set of data that i am interpolating wit a cubic spline using a UnivariateSpline of order 3 (cubic). I want to do a form of peak detection where instead of taking the derivative of the interpolation and seaching for zeros i simply take the derivative and plug it into the quadratic equation to find all the zeros.

What exactly does this function return? Because in order to generate a set of data that lay on the interpolation you must feed the returned item a list of points, like so

```
from numpy import linspace,exp
from numpy.random import randn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
x = linspace(-3, 3, 100) # original data x axis
y = exp(-x**2) + randn(100)/10  #original data y axis
s = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=1) # interpolation, returned to value s
xs = linspace(-3, 3, 1000) #values for x axis
ys = s(xs) # create new y axis
plt.plot(x, y, '.-')
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

So what exactly is this item called s that the function returns? Does it list the coefficients of the cubic? If so how would i go about finding the peaks by differentiating these values?

Answer (score 0):

The object `s` is an instance of `scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.UnivariateSpline`.

As any python object, it has some properties and methods that can be used to manipulate
them. To discover what you can do with some python object, you can always use the builtin
functions `type`, `dir` and `vars`.

In this case, `dir` will help the most. Just run

```
dir(s)
```

and you will get all the properties from `s`, which are:

```
['__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_data',
 '_eval_args',
 '_from_tck',
 '_reset_class',
 '_reset_nest',
 '_set_class',
 'antiderivative',
 'derivative',
 'derivatives',
 'get_coeffs',
 'get_knots',
 'get_residual',
 'integral',
 'roots',
 'set_smoothing_factor']
```

Python uses the convention that properties and methods with names startin with and underscore
are private, so you don't use them unless you know what you are doing. But as you can see, the
end of the list contains the information you want from `s`: it contains the spline coefficients, derivative, roots and etc.

Let's tackle the example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100) # original data x axis
y = np.exp(-x**2) + randn(100)/10  #original data y axis
s = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=1) # interpolation, returned to value s

# watch the changes
xs = np.linspace(-3, 3, 10000) #values for x axis
ys = s(xs) # create new y axis
ds = s.derivative(n=1)  # get the derivative
dy = ds(xs)  # compute it on xs
tol=1e-4  # stabilish a tolerance 
root_index = np.where((dy>-tol)&(dy<tol))  # find indices where dy is  close to zero within tolerance
root = xs[root_index]  # get the correspondent xs values
root = set(np.round(root, decimals=2).tolist())  # remove redundancy duo to tolerance
root = np.array(list(root))
print(root)
plt.plot(x, y, '.-')
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.plot(xs, dy, 'r--')  # plot the derivative
plt.vlines(root, -1, 1, lw=2, alpha=.4)  # draw vertical lines through each root
plt.hlines(0, -3, 3, lw=2, alpha=.4)  # draw a horizontal line through zero
```

Comment: thanks for the response!

I am calling `print s.roots` but it is still returning a pointer to something it seems. Where can i find the documentation to actually get the values for the roots?

Comment: how are you calling it? you need to do s.roots(). if you do s.roots it will return you the pointer to s.roots function

Comment: you were correct, i forgot parens. But i still am not sure how this helps finds the peaks of the interpolation by solving for them analytically. I need the roots of the derivative of the function (which is the peaks and troughs of the interpolation).

I am calling get_coeffs() but it returns 14 values which i am unsure how to relate to the cubic function

Comment: did you try s.derivatie()? you can do something like `ds=s.derivative()` and than call `dy = ds(xs)` and find the roots doing `np.where((dy>-1e-4)&(dy<1e-4))`